# Why do I get a null output to this Verilog code?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, flipflop, sequential-logic

I'm working on an assignment where I need to implement a sequential circuit with a d-flip-flop, but the output is null, and it doesn't output multiple times like I thought it would.

The output is `a2 = x,b1 = x,b2 = x,a1 = x`

```
module TestBench;

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    #10000
    $finish;
  end

  reg t_a, t_b, clk;
  wire a1, a2, b1, b2;
    
  initial begin
    $monitor("a2 = %b,b1 = %b,b2 = %b,a1 = %b", a2, b1, b2, a1);
    //$finish;
  end

  always #10 clk = ~clk;
  
  Main DUT0(a1, a2, b1, b2, clk, t_a, t_b);
  
  initial begin
    t_a = 0;t_b = 0;#20
    t_b = 1;#20
    t_a = 1;t_b = 0;#20
    t_b = 1;
  end
  
endmodule


module Main(L_a1, L_a2, L_b1, L_b2, clk, t_a, t_b);
  output L_a1,  L_a2,  L_b1,  L_b2;
  input t_a, t_b, clk;
  wire  s0, xor_1, nor_1, or_1, s1, nor_2, and_1, and_0, not_0;
    
  assign nor_1 = ~(s0 | s1 | t_a);
  assign nor_2 = ~(not_0 | s1 | t_b);
  assign or_1 = nor_1 | nor_2;
  
  DflipFlop DflipFlop_1(s1, , clk, or_1);
  
  assign xor_1 = s0 ^ s1;
  
  DflipFlop DflipFlop_0(s0, , clk, xor_1);
  
  assign L_b2 = s0;
  
  assign not_0 = ~s0;
  assign L_a2 = not_0;
  
  assign and_1 = s0 & s1;
  assign L_b1 = and_1;
  
  assign and_0 = not_0 & s1;
  assign L_a1 = and_0;
  
endmodule

module DflipFlop(q, q_inv, clk, d);
    parameter WIDTH = 1;
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] q, q_inv;
    input clk;
    input [WIDTH-1:0] d;

    always @ (posedge clk)
        q <= d;
    
endmodule
```

Comment: You did not initialize the clock.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems, and they all have the same root cause.

You used the Verilog `reg` type to declare some signals, which is the proper thing to do.  However, for simulation purposes, a `reg` has a default value of `x` (unknown) at time 0, and it retains the `x` value until you assign the `reg` with a known value (0 or 1).

I see you are dumping VCD waveforms.  You should use a waveform viewer to look at the internal signals of your design.  If you were to look at the inputs of the `DflipFlop_0` instance, you would see the the `clk` signal is always `x`.  This signal is driven directly from the testbench.  However, you did not initialize the signal in the testbench.  One way to do so is in an `initial` block.  For example, add this line to your testbench:

```
initial clk = 0;
```

That will allow the `clk` signal to toggle between 0 and 1 as desired.

Another problem is with the `DflipFlop_0` instance `q` output signal.  You will also see that it is always `x`, which is the default value for `reg` types as already mentioned.  This is complicated by the fact that the `d` input is also `x`, and the `d` input is a combination of the outputs of the 2 flip-flops.  Since the inputs and outputs of the flops are always unknown, the other signals which depend on them are unknown.

You need a way to initialize the flip-flop outputs to known values.  This is commonly done using a reset signal.  This reset, like the clock, would be a common signal which is an input to the top-level design module and would be driven by the testbench.

Here is an example of a flip-flop with an asynchronous reset:

```
module DflipFlop0 (q, rst, clk, d);
    parameter WIDTH = 1;
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] q;
    input rst;
    input clk;
    input [WIDTH-1:0] d;

    always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
        if (rst) begin
            q <= 0;
        end else begin
            q <= d;
        end
    end    
endmodule
```

I removed the `q_inv` output since you weren't using it.